# An instance of the equality of the transition rates $W_{i\to f}$ and $W_{f\to i}$ from Fermi's Golden rule

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, fermis-golden-rule

Fermi's Golden Rule tells that for a perturbing Hamiltonian $\hat{V}$ that couples initial state $\left| i \right\rangle$ to final state $\left| f \right\rangle$, the transition probability per unit time is given by:
$$
W_{i \to f} = \frac{2\pi}{\hbar} \left| \langle f | \hat{V} | i \rangle \right|^2 \rho(E_f)
$$
where $\rho(E_f)$ is the density of states at the energy $E_f$ of the final state. In quantum mechanics, for hermitian perturbation $\hat{V}$, it holds that:
$$
\left| \langle f | \hat{V} | i \rangle \right|^2 = \left| \langle i | \hat{V} | f \rangle \right|^2.
$$
But as can be easily seen, this is not enough to claim $W_{i \to f}=W_{f \to i}$. We further require that $$\rho(E_f)=\rho(E_i)$$ holds.

Can somebody give at least one physical example (from quantum mechanics, atomic physics, etc) where the equality ($W_{i \to f}=W_{f \to i}$) holds, and one where it fails to hold? This point is not well-addressed in textbooks.

Comment: Something with a discrete spectrum would be an easy example where it holds

Comment: See the article on laser [Transition Cross-sections](https://www.rp-photonics.com/transition_cross_sections.html) in the RP Photonics Encyclopedia